# Keep counter value across different users

Tags: javascript, html, local-storage

I'm making a site which counts the amount of homework one does, but i'm having a hard time storing the counter value across different pc's since i am using local storage, which stores it only in the browser storage. Is there a way to "save" the value over the internet and access it from any pc?

Comment: Databases. something like mysql or sql server i guess.

Comment: Local Storage is not accessible from outside the browser. You have to use a small server with a Database System. Get some cheap shared hosting somewhere :)

Comment: For something simple like this you could also just use a plain text file.

Comment: @Barmar i'm quite a beginner.could you tell me how could i ? i mean what should i add in the text file? the name of the variable?and then modify it with javascript?

Comment: Probably shouldn't mention this, but for really small scale like this, sites like jsFiddle, pastebin, github,  etc. can be used to store data as well, but they probably won't like it for anything larger than "homework". There's also sites like http://myjson.com/ that lets you store snippets of json

Comment: Since local storage is only on that PC it is considered Client Side, You will need a server side storage (database).
If you are using a .net then you will want to code it in VB or C#
If you are not using .net you could use a language like PHP.

Comment: @adeneo thats a great idea!!! lol

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can save the counter in a file. You'll need to use a server-side language for this, here's a PHP example.

```
<?php
$file = fopen("counter.txt", "r+");
flock($file, LOCK_EX); // Block other users
$counter = trim(fgets($file));
$counter++;
rewind($file); // Go back to beginning of the file
fwrite($file, "$counter\n");
fclose($file); // This will unlock the file, too

echo $counter;
```

Comment: and if i want to modify that value when pressing a button, what code should i add? thanks a lot just for this

Comment: The button's `onclick` function should use AJAX to call the PHP script.

Comment: and also if i had multiple values, since i display the values in a table of the whole class, should i use a vector in a for or?

Comment: Now you're getting more complicated. What are these multiple counters? Which ones should get incremented? You could use an associative array, but then you need a way of indicating which counter to use. You'll need to encode the file, using `json_encode` or `serialize`. With this complexity, you're probably better off using a database.

Comment: i was talking about a counter for each student and each should increment on the press of a specific button, and i was thinking about something like an array counter[i] and know them by their index

Comment: but you might be right about better using a database since it wouldn't be that complicated i guess

Comment: Right. You're probably going to eventually want to store more information about the students, and it will be easier to add that in a database.

Comment: @Gothdo I've updated the answer to say that this problem generally requires a server-side language, and this is an example.

Answer (score 1):

I made a little wrapper around myjson.com that can be used for simple storage.

```
var store = {
    create: function(params) {
        var def = $.Deferred();
        $.ajax({
            url: "https://api.myjson.com/bins",
            type: "POST",
            data: JSON.stringify(params),
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json"
        }).done(function(data) {
            def.resolve(data.uri.split('/').pop())
        });
        return def.promise();
    },
    update: function(id, params) {
        return $.ajax({
            url: "https://api.myjson.com/bins/" + id,
            type: "PUT",
            data: JSON.stringify(params),
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json"
        });
    },
    get: function(id) {
        return $.get("https://api.myjson.com/bins/" + id);
    }
}
```

First you create an instance, and get an ID back, you only have to do this once to set it up and have somewhere to store data

```
store.create({users : 0}).done(function(id) {
    console.log(id);
});
```

make sure you save the ID, as you'll use this later to update and get data from the instance you've just created.
Note the object passed in, that's the data we're saving, and it can be updated later.

Now to get the data, you'd just do

```
store.get(':id').done(function(data) {
    console.log(data); // the data you've stored
});
```

and to update the data you'll do

```
store.update('4iln9', {users : 2}).done(function(data) {
    console.log(data); // returns the updated data
});
```

And for a quick example of a count -> **http://jsfiddle.net/dcp6e0g0/**

Comment: that seems interesting.one thing, if i were to have more counters, how could i add them to myjson?

Comment: `store.create({users1 : 0, users2: 3, users3: 111})` you can create as many as you'd like in the object passed in, and then update them as you'd like, just note that updating overwrites the entire object, so all keys/values must be present, which means you could also add or remove keys/values with a `update()` call.